# SwiperJS - Two-way control not working with ReactJS (NextJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, swiper.js

Tried copy and pasting the example code in the docs (https://swiperjs.com/react#controller):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Controller } from 'swiper';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';

const App = () => {
    // store swiper instances
    const [firstSwiper, setFirstSwiper] = useState(null);
    const [secondSwiper, setSecondSwiper] = useState(null);

    return (
        <main>
        <Swiper
            modules={[Controller]}
            onSwiper={setFirstSwiper}
            controller={{ control: secondSwiper }}
         >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>

      <Swiper
        modules={[Controller]}
        onSwiper={setSecondSwiper}
        controller={{ control: firstSwiper }}
      >
        {/* ... */}
      </Swiper>
    </main>
  );
};
```

And got the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`
[image: error message]

It doesn't have anything to do with the rest of my code as I've experimented with it using a new empty file on the same project.
The lines causing the error are:

`controller={{ control: firstSwiper }}`

and

`controller={{ control: secondSwiper }}`

I'd also like to know if it's possible to link 4 swipers with each other, using the same method.
Thanks.

I tried isolating the piece of code so that it's solely the docs' code, to rule out the possibility that it's a problem with my own code - still threw the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6216 This should solve your issue.

Comment: Please check GitHub Issues next time you think that it's a library issue and not a you issue.

Comment: If you are using NextJS 13 with app directory you need to add 'use client' at the top of the page to support Third party libraries and states